# How to find second alias name of enum given first name?

Tags: c#, enums

I have two Enums:

```
public enum test1 {
   t1=1,
   t2=0 
}
public enum test2 {
   tt1 = test1.t1,
   tt2= test1.t2 
}
```

If I have knowledge about tt1, Can I retrieve t1 from it. I want to use like dictionary having knowledge of key, one can get value corresponding to that key.

Still getting correct output using below statement:

```
var kkk = (test1) test2.tt1 ;
```

Comment: can you provide an example of using the result you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the code you have displayed is a bit confusing because `test1` is zero-based so declaring `test2` like this:

```
public enum test2 {
   tt1,
   tt2 
}
```

would be analogous.

Notwithstanding, if I had a `test2` value, say `tt1`, I could in fact cast that to a `test1` value:

```
var t = (test1)test2.tt1;
```

because they share the same underlying `int` value. So, you could hypothetically have a dictionary, `Dictionary<test1, object>`, and get a value from it with a `test2` variable:

```
var val = d[(test1)test2.tt1];
```

Comment: If underlying int value is not same then what will happen. I am sure that both enums are not sharing same int value.

Comment: @User1551892, they are. Did you see how the `test2` enum was declared?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is: No.

Initial values of enums must be known in compiling time. The compiler then convert it to (in your case) to int.

So the test1.t2 will have 1, and test2.tt2 will have the same value. But from code view this will be just two identical value, not related at all.

If you want to know exactly from enum tt2 take value you will have to use eg. some custom attribute and receive this information via reflection.

Or just populate dictionary your self (manually)

```
        Dictionary<test1, test2> dict = new Dictionary<test1, test2>() {
            { test1.t1, test2.tt1 }, 
            { test1.t2, test2.tt2 }, 
        };
```